# Can't debug Razor helper - seems IIS is not compiling with debugging symbols?

Tags: c#, iis, razor

I am trying to debug a Razor helper function which is running locally on IIS.

Even when my helper code reads:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

The breakpoint does not occur.

So I think it is because IIS fails to compile the function in debug mode.

I added this in web.config but it doesn't solve the issue:

```
<compilation debug="true"></compilation>
```

Surely somebody else has run into this, or is just my particular laptop buggy???

Thanks!
- Brian

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out, man what a wild goose chase!

I forgot the "@" symbol when calling the helper. My code looked like this:

```
MyHelper()
```

But it should look like this:

```
@MyHelper()
```

It seems in this case Razor doesn't even CALL the function, or perhaps calls it but with debug mode off, anyway I added the "@" symbol and then could trace in with the debugger again.

Seems lots of little pitfalls like that, with this Razor thingee...

Hope that helps somebody avoid losing 2 hours of their day. :-(

Comment: Are you able to actually step through to debug to the @MyHelper()?  I have a helper and when I try to step into it it skips over it but shows the results of the helper code on the web page, but I'd like to be able to step into the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I had the same problem.